# Create Unique Number from Two Values; Bit Shifting?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with IDs and locales.  The same ID can be listed more than once with a different locale:

```
ID      Locale
123456  EN_US
234567  EN_US
234567  EN_CA
345678  EN_US
```

I need to create an unique identifier in the form of an numeric ID (Integer) for each record, while maintaining the ability to reverse engineer the original components.

I was thinking bit shifting might work: assign a numerical value to each locale, but I'm not quite sure how to implement.  Has anyone faced this challenge before? Also, I have 75 locales so I'm not sure if that would be an issue with bit shifting.

Lastly, I'm using SQL Server with a Linked Server connection to Teradata (that's my data source).  I don't think Teradata supports bitwise out-of-the-box so I'm assuming I'll have to do it in MSSQL.

Thank you.

Comment: why not just concatenate the values, e.g. `234567-EN_US` and `234567-EN_CA`?

Comment: The new ID needs to be an Integer.

Comment: Then assign numeric values to all of the locale codes and concatenate the numeric values, result should either be int or bigint then.

Comment: @GaryWalker he needs also restore.

Comment: This would never fit an INT. youd need much bigger number to represent the whole record.

Comment: Not as clear as I should have been perhaps. He has 75 unique values. Using these as the last 2 digits. Easily separated by modulo 100 arithmetic

Comment: Actually I think @GaryWalker 's approach would work.  I'd prefix with something like 999 to indicate this is a combined ID and suffix with 01 to 75 to reflect the locale.  I can then reverse engineer with string parsing.  A solution so simply of course I didn't think of it :)  How do I give Gary credit?

Comment: @GaryWalker I got you now .  yes . he should have a seperate locale to number mapping and then he can do that.

Comment: @GaryWalker Also , computed persistant column would be great here.

Comment: Added "answer" summarizing what I said ealier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a composite numeric key, mapping your 75 unique values into the last 2 digits of the numeric key. You can parse into components with simple modulus 100 arithmetic or just a substring. If you will ever exceed 100 values, use 3 digits instead. 9 digits total will fit int an int, 10-18 will fit in a bigint.

Answer (score 0):

Converting 234567-EN_US into an integer is easy.  Just use CHECKSUM on the concatenated string value.  It would not be reversible, however.

You could store this CHECKSUM value on the original table, however, and then use it to backtrack from whatever table you're going to store the integer in.

Another solution would be to assign each locale an Integer value (as Marc B suggested).  Call that X.  Then call your existing integer ID (234567) as Y.  Your final key would be (X * 1,000,000) + Y.  You could then reverse the formula to get the values back.  This would only work, of course, if your existing integer IDs are well below 1,000,000, and also if your final integer can be a BigInt.

Comment: Checksum will map many possible source values into a single integer value; This could be problem.